# Can someone help me with my __gt__ and also help me with using __radd__?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not sure what I am doing wrong with my `__gt__` but I am not getting the correct results. I have tried changing things around but I don't always get a correct print out. Also, I don't really understand the `__radd__` or how to implement it. And another quick question when I get my print out sometimes I get answers like 2 0/6 how could I get it to just print out a 2?

here is my code:

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self,top,bottom):
        self.num = top
        self.den = bottom
        self.gcd = gcd(self.num, self.den)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.den == 0:
            return str(0)
        elif self.num >= self.den:
            if self.den == 1:
                return str(self.num)
            else:
                return str(self.num // self.den)+\
                   ' '+str(self.num%self.den)+\
                   '/'+str(self.den)
        else:
            return str(self.num)+"/"+str(self.den)

    def show(self):
        print(self.num,"/",self.den)

    def __add__(self,otherfraction):
        newnum = self.num*otherfraction.den + \
                     self.den*otherfraction.num
        newden = self.den * otherfraction.den
        common = self.gcd
        return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)

    def __sub__(self,otherfraction):
        if self.den == 1:
            sub = self.num - otherfraction.num
            return sub
        else:
            newnum = self.num*otherfraction.den - \
                         self.den*otherfraction.num
            newden = self.den * otherfraction.den
            common = self.gcd
            return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)

    def __mul__(self,otherfraction):
        newnum = self.num*otherfraction.num 
        newden = self.den * otherfraction.den

        return Fraction(newnum//newnum,newden//newnum)

    def __truediv__(self,otherfraction):
        newnum = self.num*otherfraction.den 
        newden = self.den * otherfraction.num
        common = self.gcd
        return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)

    def __gt__(self,other):
        if self.den == 1:
            if self.num > other.num:
                return self.num
        else:
            frac1 = self.num*other.den 
            frac2 = self.den * other.num
            if frac1 > frac2:
                return self.num//self.den
            else:
                return other.num//other.den
    def __radd__(self, other):
        if other == 0:
            return self
        else:
            return self.__add__(other)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        firstnum = self.num * other.den
        secondnum = other.num * self.den

        return firstnum == secondnum

def gcd(m,n):
    while m%n != 0:
        oldm = m
        oldn = n

        m = oldn
        n = oldm%oldn
    return n


def main():

        getNum1 = int(input("Enter a numerator 1: "))
        getDen1 = int(input("Enter a denominator 1: "))

        getNum2 = int(input("Enter a numerator 2: "))
        getDen2 = int(input("Enter a denominator 2: "))

        f1 = Fraction(getNum1,getDen1)
        f2 = Fraction(getNum2,getDen2)

        print("[",f1,"]","[",f2,"]",sep='')

        f3 = f1 + f2
        print("Adding Fractions:",f3)
        f3 = f1 - f2
        print("Subtracting Fraction:",f3)

        f3 = f1 * f2

        print("Multiply Fraction:",f3)

        f3 = f1 / f2
        print("Dividing Fraction:",f3)

        if f1 > f2:
            print(f1,"Greater than",f2)
        else:
            print(f2,"Greater than",f1)

        if f1 == f2:
            print("Fractions are equal")
        else:
            print("Fractions are not equal")



main()
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `__gt__()` method? Do you want to return true when `self` is greater than `other` ?

Comment: Yeah I'm just trying to have it return self if true or return other depending which fraction is greater than the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments -

> Yeah I'm just trying to have it return self if true or return other depending which fraction is greater than the other.

Seems like you are misunderstanding how `__gt__()` works, this function should return 'True' (or a true like value) when self is greater than the other, and it should return `False` (or a false like value , like 0, etc) , when `self` is less than the `other` . Lets take your example (assumming `__gt__()` returns the `self`'s value when self is greater otherwise the `other`'s value) , when you do -

```
if f1 > f2:
```

This would call the `__gt__()` function which would return either self's value or other's value, both of them are `true` like values, unless they return 0 , assuming the latter is not the case. This would always result in `f1` being considered greater , since you are returning the values (which have a `True` like value) instead of `True` or 'False`.

You should return something like -

```
def __gt__(self,other):
    if self.num/self.den > other.num/other.den:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Also regarding `radd` -

`__radd__` is reverse add. When Python tries to evaluate x + y it first attempts to call `x.__add__(y)` . If this fails then it falls back to `y.__radd__(x)` .

This is pretty useful when evaluating `sum()` over a list of objects, I believe the first call in `sum()` is actually a call to `__radd__()` , You can check this out [here](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html) .

Example of where `__radd__()` comes into picture, lets say you are doing -

```
>>> 0 + f1 # where f1 is your object.
```

This would end up calling `f1.__radd__(0)` .

This is case with `sum()` , because `sum()` starts with an initial value of `0` and starts adding the elements in the list to it one by one.

Comment: Okay thanks that makes sense for__gt__ but I still don't understand how I would use_radd__ for this program cause I don't think evaluating sum(). Sorry this one just has me really confused.

Comment: Please check my latest answer, please let me know if its still unclear.

Comment: Okay that kinda makes sense but I just don't understand what I would be trying to sum() in my program like I don't see how im suppose to use this in the program sorry for being a pain

Comment: @keggy It looks like you understand `__radd__` the way you've implemented it. You rely on `0+self==self` and `other+self==self+other` which is fine when `self` is a rational number. Hovewer your implementation of `__add__` doesn't handle the situation where `other` is something else than a rational number (which may or may not be okay depending on your purpose).

Comment: So the way I have it does work just as long as other is a rational number correct? @skyking

Comment: @keggy For the adding part yes. Unless I've missed something more or less obvious. Do you get results that shows otherwise?

Comment: @skyking honestly I just didn't understand what it was suppose to be doing I just found info on online and just through it in there

Comment: @keggy Your `__radd__()` function is good enough I believe, for your usecase.

Comment: Try creating a list of Fraction objects and then do `sum(<that list>)` .